# Javascirpt validation regex does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

I just can't find out why this pattern doesn't work. Seems that everything is right and I don't what I'm missing. Every single time it falls into else section and I can't figure out why.

```
var adresaFormat = /^[A-ZČĆŽŠĐ][a-zčćžšđ]+([ ][A-ZČĆŽŠĐa-zčćžšđ][a-zčćžšđ]+)+[0-9]{1,3}$/;
document.getElementById("adresa").addEventListener("blur",function(){
    if(adresaFormat.test(document.getElementById("adresa").value)){
        document.getElementById("adresa").style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
        document.getElementById("adresa").style.border="1px solid #c2c2c2";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("adresa").style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("adresa").style.border="1px solid #ff0000";
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the example string you are using for the test?

Comment: Sure. "Unknown street 2"

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, everything that isn't visible within posted code is type of the field. And it is text.

Comment: [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5BA-Z%C4%8C%C4%86%C5%BD%C5%A0%C4%90%5D%5Ba-z%C4%8D%C4%87%C5%BE%C5%A1%C4%91%5D%2B%28%5B%20%5D%5BA-Z%C4%8C%C4%86%C5%BD%C5%A0%C4%90a-z%C4%8D%C4%87%C5%BE%C5%A1%C4%91%5D%5Ba-z%C4%8D%C4%87%C5%BE%C5%A1%C4%91%5D%2B%29%2B%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%24%2F) will show you why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the space between the second word and the number.

```js
//Before
var adresaFormat = /^[A-ZČĆŽŠĐ][a-zčćžšđ]+([ ][A-ZČĆŽŠĐa-zčćžšđ][a-zčćžšđ]+)+[0-9]{1,3}$/;

console.log(adresaFormat.test("Unknown street 2"));
//After
adresaFormat = /^[A-ZČĆŽŠĐ][a-zčćžšđ]+([ ][A-ZČĆŽŠĐa-zčćžšđ][a-zčćžšđ]+)[ ]+[0-9]{1,3}$/;

console.log(adresaFormat.test("Unknown street 2"));
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly! I don't know how I haven't seen that immediately. Thanks a lot!